# Secuity considerations when including files

Tags: php, security, include, get

I am preparing to setup a request routing system in php based on the $_GET array.

For example, for the url `?r=login` I'd use include `myfiles/".$_GET['r'].".php";`
Which would point automatically to myfiles/login.php

I know I need to sanitise the get input, but I'm concerned as it is possible to maliciously redirect the include. Can anyone suggest how to prevent this? Also can I check the file actually exists before calling it?

I have some ideas of my own, I just want to know I've not missed any considerations.

Comment: If I were to set the include with an absolute path before the get variable, would that prevent redirects off site? (I am thinking of putting the includes above the web root, out of public veiw).

Answer (score 5):

It is always a good idea not to include files specified through a url. If you still want to do that, use a `switch` statement or any `array` to filter the stuff and include only what you need:

**Example 1:**

```
$page = $_GET[...];

switch($page){
  case 'login': include 'login_page.php'; break;
  // and so on
  default: die("bye bad guy !");
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
$page = $_GET[...];

$pages = array('page1.php', 'page2.php', 'page3.php');

if( in_array($page, $pages) )
{
    include($page);
{
else
{
   die("bye bad guy !");
}
```

I would suggest you to have a look at these related security tuts:

- [PHP 5.2.0 and allow_url_include](http://blog.php-security.org/archives/45-PHP-5.2.0-and-allow_url_include.html)
- [PHP Security Mistakes](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/PHP-Security-Mistakes/)
- [Top 7 PHP Security Blunders](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/php-security-blunders)

Comment: Is there a better way to setup a routing system in PHP?

Comment: @YsoL8: Have a look at example 2 in my answer. That is the one I can think of for the kind of situation you are in.

Comment: I was hoping to set the path automatically to help keep the structure consistent. You would be against that?

Comment: @YsoL8: Nope i am not; the whole idea is that you should do it in such way that if users modify your url from the browser, they should not be able to include any malicious script.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use whitelist. If you can't, then:

- allow underscore and alphanumeric characters only
- put the include files into a separate directory